# How do you solve $10=(x-2)e^{x^2-5}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So we have been thinking about how to solve this equation but we can’t really figure out how to solve it by hand. Is there any trick or is it just not possible? The equation is:
$$10=(x-2)e^{x^2-5}$$

Comment: It is possible, if you allow the definition of a new, nonstandard function called the Lambert W function - and more precisely generalized versions of it. With that search term, you may find relevant questions on math.SE

Comment: Yeah thank you I just found something about it, it was a Math task for a student and we were just wondering if we were just overseeing something of if it was too complicated. So it definetly was too complicated lol.

Comment: Are you sure that the task really was to *solve* the equation, and not something like determining *how many* solutions it has? The former seems hopeless (unless the question was about finding approximate solutions by numerical methods), but the latter is easy.

Answer (score 4):

*All done by hand (knowing only the value of $\log(10)$)*

Consider that you look for the zero of function$$f(x)=(x-2)\,e^{x^2-5}-10$$ It is clear (I hope) that the solution is larger than $2$ but the problem is that this function veries extremely fast because of the exponential. So, instead, consider that you look for the zero of
$$g(x)=\log\Big[(x-2)\,e^{x^2-5}\Big]-\log(10)$$ that is to say
$$g(x)=(x^2-5)+\log(x-2)-\log(10)$$ We have $g(3)=4-\log(10) >0$ while $g(x)$ tends to $-\infty$ when $x \to 2^+$.

So, use one step of Newton method with $x_0=3$ and
$$g'(x)=2x+\frac 1{x-2}$$
$$g'(3)=7 \implies x_1=3-\frac {4-\log(10)}7=\frac{17+\log (10)}{7} =2.75751$$ while, numerically, the solution is $x=2.75406$.

*For the fun*, change the $10$ by $10^k$ and use exactly the same, that is to say
$$x_1=\frac{17+k\log (10)}{7}$$ Some results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 2.75751 &  2.75406 \\
 2 & 3.08645 &  3.08590 \\
 3 & 3.41539 &  3.40150 \\
 4 & 3.74433 &  3.69871 \\
 5 & 4.07328 &  3.97875 \\
 6 & 4.40222 &  4.24352
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Doing the same with Halley method,
$$x_1=\frac{226+17 k \log (10)}{94+k \log (10)}$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 2.75324 &  2.75406 \\
 2 & 3.08592 &  3.08590 \\
 3 & 3.40342 &  3.40150 \\
 4 & 3.70676 &  3.69871 \\
 5 & 3.99685 &  3.97875 \\
 6 & 4.27456 &  4.24352
\end{array}
\right)$$

*(Here, I cheated : I used my phone for the divisions)*

Comment: Can I know why g(x) can still have the same zero as f(x) after taking the log? Also why did you write log(10)? What made you take log here?

Comment: @Mardia. It is the same equation. I took the log of rhs and lhs, that's it

Comment: Shouldn't 10 also be included inside the bracket? Why does taking out the 10 and taking log not effect the zero?

Comment: @Mardia. Look at the equation as written in title an take log of ech side

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: This is a really cool solution, thank you!